# Disable text wrapping in vim

Tags: formatting

There's a very weird thing that occurs when I type a comment that it inserts a newline after a max-width which I don't want to have done. For example: here is me typing it in: https://gyazo.com/7dd2fccd0d988082abf2e6f8a9be945e.

Why does this occur?

The only (hackish) way I was able to disable it is to set `:set paste`, but hopefully there's a better way to disable this autowrapping?

```
    "When in normal mode, treat an enter like insert -- as I continue typing this
    line it automatically adds a new line
    :nmap <leader>&  O
    :nmap <CR> i<CR>
```

Comment: Please include output of `:set formatoptions? comments? textwidth?`, the combination of these three should define the behavior of automatically wrapping lines, in particular comment lines.

Comment: @filbranden cool! I never knew you could do `:set whatever?` and it would tell you what the current setting was. Doing that helped me figure it out -- setting `textwidth=0` fixed it for me.

Comment: But `set tw=0` is not necessarily the only or best way to fix this... I tried to reproduce your issue on a `*.vim` file and while mine wraps the lines, it starts the wrapped line with a comment character... So I was curious why your setup seems to be acting differently...